# magento extension for ask questions to customer based on the answer display related products

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am novice to magento.I need to create one extension.It is  used to display the question when i click category link.The customer must answer for that question then next question display on the screen customer answer for that it still some of questions customer must answer.Then related products are displayed based on the answers given by the customers.

```
 Example:Your skin colour is? options are available like 1.white   2.black   3.brown.
```

I also searched in google for the extension but i didn't saw the related extension.Can any one suggest for this? Advance Thanks

Comment: you can use `magento poll` for this..... , check this link for more details : http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-manage-polls.html#gref

Comment: thanks for your reply.I need the question directly present  in the center not poll.The category is selected then the some questions  one by one  visible to the customer ,customer must answer for the question based on the answer related products are displayed in the magento using extension.Can you please suggest any extension perform these functionality?

Comment: i guess, you can use css to move `polls` to `center` , you can search here once : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

Comment: i tried in the magento connect already also i tried know but FAQ and product page having questions based extension are present but what i expect i didn't saw in these magento connect.Any other way to get this functionality please suggest

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DhivyaPriya try post here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/, you may get solution....

Comment: thank u for giving this link.I will try using this url.